# closing db connection with django's persistent connection in a multi-threaded script

Tags: django, multithreading, persistent-connection, connection-close

Django 1.6 introduces a [Persistent Connections feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/databases/#persistent-connections). However I've noticed that exiting a script that uses django's ORM leaves at least some of the connections open on the db side.
Setup: django 1.6.0, postgres 9.2 and psycopg2 2.5.1.

How do you gracefully close the connection to the database from a script?

The [caveats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/databases/#caveats) section mentions that django opens a connection per thread, so in a multi-threaded script, does django create a connection per thread, even for threads that do not access the db?
Does each thread need to close the db connection separately?

If the answer to both questions above is yes, what can you do with daemon threads (e.g. for comm) which do not join on script exit?

Comment: Hi, I'm using a similar setup and having the same issues of dandling connections. Have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue just now...

Solved it by calling the following code when my thread exits:

```
from django.db import close_old_connections
close_old_connections()
```

Comment: this answer doesn't deal with the complexities of multi-threading

Answer (score 8):

I just upgraded and had this come up and `close_old_connections` in the main process before launching the sub processes does not work like the old `close_connections` did to give each process their own connection. But if you looked at what `close_connections` use to do you can recreate it [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/db/).

So I do this in my main process before creating my sub processes.

```
from django.db import connections
for conn in connections.all():
    conn.close()
```

And it works great. The new `close_old_connections` will only close the connection if it has expired or has gone away.